# MVC view looks smaller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET, My view is based on a class I created.. but when I open the view on browser It looks a bit smaller than usual..

My view:

```
@model Work.Models.WorkClass

<html>
<head>

<link href="~/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/pikaday.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Report","Home",FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete= "off" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h2>WorkClass</h2>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10" id="date">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.time, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.time, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.time, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    var picker = new Pikaday({
        field: document.getElementById('date'),
        firstDay: 0,
        minDate: new Date('2000-01-01'),
        maxDate: new Date('2020-12-31'),
        yearRange: [2000, 2020],
        numberOfMonths: 1
    });
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I noticed when I remove this code the view returns to it's proper size:

```
<link href="~/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/pikaday.js"></script>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: It sounds like your referenced CSS files are causing issue.  Can you provide content of those files, or even some screenshots to really showcase the issue? It doesn't sound that .Net MVC is really your problem here.

Comment: As @parameter said, probably there's something in the css files that is setting the font-weight

Comment: @parameter They are downloaded from https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday

Comment: @MeMyselfAndi thanks.  By the looks of it, the site.css file is what is giving you problems.  Can you confirm that your issue goes away when only removing the link to that stylesheet?

Comment: @parameter Yes, you're right. The problem is in site.css file. When I remove it, the view looks proper, since this specific file is not crucial for me I'll remove it. Thanks!!

Comment: @MeMyselfAndi if my answer helped you with this issue, please mark my answer below as the accepted answer :) Glad to help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating, the fix was to remove the linked stylesheet `site.css`.  It contains undesirable markup affecting the look and feel of your page.